# A basic question about hypothesis test and rejection region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, t-test

If we want to test the hypothesis $H_0$: $\mu = 0$, where $H_a$: $\mu \neq 0$. Then the t statistic is $t=\bar{y}/(s/\sqrt{n})$ and 95% confidence interval is $\bar{y} \pm t_{.975}s/\sqrt{n}$ by t-test. If the sample mean $\bar{y} > 0$, why the rejection region is $t>t_{.975}$ instead of $t<-t_{.975}$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question - the rejection region for a two-tailed test will be $|t| > t_{0.975}$ (i.e. $t>t_{0.975}$ or $t<-t_{0.975}$) regardless of the value of $\bar{y}$?